# Наследование proxy-моделей в django

Tags: python, django

Всем доброго дня! 
Не могу разгадать ребус, чем отличается наследование обычных моделей и proxy-моделей. Насколько я понял, при наследовании обычной модели, например:

```
class A(Model):
   a = models.TextField()
   c = models.TextField()
class B(A):
   b = models.TextField()
```

поля a и c класса B будут храниться в таблице модели A вместе с полями а и c класса A. И переопределить их в дочернем классе как-то так:

```
class B(A):
   b = models.TextField()
   a = models.IntegerField()
```

уже нельзя. Про proxy встречал информацию, что вроде позволяют что-то менять в поведении дочерних моделей. Но насколько я понял, то они тоже хранят наследуемые поля в таблице, относящейся к моделям родителя.. то есть в прокси их тоже нельзя переопределить? В общем, в чем преимущество использования proxy моделей? Ведь добавлять поля и методы в дочернем классе можно и при обычном наследовании. И возможно ли в django в принципе переопределение полей родительской модели (не абстрактной)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы просто наследуетесь от другой модели, то создаёте так называемое multi-table наследование. То есть у вас будет две таблицы.
[русскоязычная документация](https://djbook.ru/rel1.9/topics/db/models.html#multi-table-inheritance)

Тогда из дочерней модели можно обращаться к полям родительской так, как будто это её собственные поля. Но это будет всё-же две таблицы.

В случае с прокси-моделями, вы не меняете всё что касается данных. То есть у вас по прежнему будет одна таблица, но вы можете задать другое поведение.

Comment: Получается, переопределить поля родителя нельзя ни при каком условии?

Comment: @Александр, не могу вспомнить ответ на этот вопрос. Можно абстрактную модель сделать и те поля которые с одинаковым именем, но с разными свойствами, определить уже в дочерних моделях.